# Problem with back button

Tags: buttons

My Lumia 430 was dropped down by my running bike. Nothing happened to display but back button is not functioning properly. Please tell me how can i switch on screen back button or virtual back button.

Answer (score 0):

Press once on the Windows button to get back on the main screen.
But the apps continue to run in background. If it's physical button maybe it doesn't make good contact.